# how to show overlapped the title over the collectionview in swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to build a photo gallery like iPhone but I´m having trouble with CollectionView. The title is not showing itself and I don't know why.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width/3, height: view.frame.width/3)
    
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
    view.addSubview(titleView)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.addSubview(button)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
        titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 16),
        titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: 16),
        titleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor, constant: -16),
        
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 200),
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    ])
}
```

[image: app]

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints are conflicting.

First: Set a height to the TitleView.

Second: Set only one binding between the title view and the collection view. You're setting it twice with different options.

```swift
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    titleView.topAnchor.constraint(
       equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16
    ),
    titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
       equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 16
    ),
    titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: -16
    ),
    titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(
       equalToConstant: 80
    ),
    
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor
    ),
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor
    ),
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor
    ),
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.bottomAnchor
    ),
    
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8
    ),
    button.rightAnchor.constraint(
      equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8
    ),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(
      equalToConstant: 50
    ),
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(
      equalToConstant: 50
    )
  ])
```

Comment: how would you do it?

Comment: the view is in blank after the changes